# CSS Menu Background Height and Text Height

Tags: css, button, menu, height

I am trying to use a background image and/or color behind my menu items.  Using either the image or just a background color the background will only match the height of the text.  The height of the background needs to be 30px and the text needs to 16px and centered - like a normal button.  I've tried every combination of css I can think of but can not get the results I'm looking for.

```
    #menu-container {
    /*float: left;*/
width: 960px;
margin:50px auto 0 auto;
height:50px;
    }

    #menu ul {
text-align: left;
height:50px;
    }


    #menu ul li {
display: inline;
background-image: url(images/menubutton.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

     #menu ul li a {
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 13px;
padding-left: 13px;
font-size: 16px;
    /*line-height: 0.2em;*/
color: #000;
font-style: normal;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
     Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
font-weight: 400;
    }

    #menu ul li a:hover {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: none
    }
```

Comment: You mean something like that? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ktedj

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #a0a0a0; /* I changed this for testing */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Basically, it used to be `display: inline` which prevented you from being able to adjust the height. You also can't use `display: block` because then they will not all be on the same line. So, `display: inline-block` is exactly what you need.
Then I added `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` with `7px` each to keep the text in the middle.

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/d7MJ8/)

Hope this helped.